# Rails precompile assets in production - different than in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have in my application.css this:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require styles
 *= require custom
 *= require paggination
 *= require colorbox
 *= require registration
 *= require ../vendor/dark
```

On development everything is OK but when I move to production, also some other assets must be precompiled because site looks different in production.

Does Rails precompile also other css files from assets folder, not only this required? I have many other css in assets folder.

Comment: The key here will be what you mean by "site looks different in production" - how does it look different?

Answer (score 0):

Rails by default only precompiles `application.css`
If you need to add individual css files, maybe if you need specific styles on certain pages you need to add them like this.

```
# in config/production.rb
# application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
config.assets.precompile += %w(frontpage.css login.css)
```

Note: You list only the `css` ending even though it's a `scss` file you have.
Then you can reference your stylesheets in your view files.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "frontpage" %>
```

Edit: And of course don't forget to do

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```